# Rendering as an image makes Blender re-render three times

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

My Blender file has started to render a scene three times.

After the render is fully complete, Blender is rendering the same frame, same scene 2 more times.

What is causing this? I am rendering in Cycles, and I do not think I have any denoising going on.

[image: Gif showing a rendering as an image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple [**View Layers**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html#id1) with **Use for Rendering** set to true in the **View Layer Properties** tab.

[image]

Turn this little guy off.

[image]